# Angular2 Service Unit Test Fails with TypeError: undefined is not an object

Tags: testing, angular, karma-runner

I am testing my authService. This is the full Test, yet Karma tells me, authService is undefined. I have plenty of Service which AuthService depends upon, but I provided and injected them all properly.

> Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'AuthService'(BackendService, Store, LoggerService, undefined, ErrorService). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'AuthService' is decorated with Injectable. in /var/folders/zb/tpysrhsx7hbg1dnsn4gwtqq00000gn/T/8715f9a6c29e748f52c8f59e3e1daae3.browserify (line 34976)

**authservice.spec.ts**

```
import { provide } from "@angular/core";
import { AuthHttp } from "angular2-jwt";
import { HTTP_PROVIDERS, XHRBackend } from "@angular/http";
import { MockBackend } from "@angular/http/testing";
import {
    TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS,
    TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS
} from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing";
import {
    beforeEachProviders,
    inject,
    beforeEach,
    it,
    describe,
    setBaseTestProviders
} from "@angular/core/testing";
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";
import { AuthService } from "./auth.service";
import { BackendService } from "../../backend/backend.service";
import { ErrorService } from "../../error/error.service";
import { LoggerService } from "../../logger/logger.service";
import { NavService } from "../../nav/nav-service/nav.service";
import { Store } from "@ngrx/store";
import { TestComponentBuilder } from "@angular/compiler/testing";
import { ToastController, AlertController } from "ionic-angular";
setBaseTestProviders(TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS, TEST_BROWSER_DYNAMIC_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS);

describe("AuthService", () => {

    let response = new Subject();
    let tcb;
    let authService;
    let navService;
    let backendService;
    let errorService;
    let store;
    let loggerService;

    class StubErrorService extends ErrorService {
        constructor() {
            super(null, null);
        }

        toast(title) {
            console.error(title);
        }

        modal(title, subtitle) {
            console.error(title, subtitle);
        }
    }

    class StubBackendService extends BackendService {

    }

    class StubStore extends Store<any> {

    }

    class StubLoggerService extends LoggerService {

    }

    class StubNavService extends NavService {

    }

    // PROVIDE

    beforeEachProviders(() => [
        HTTP_PROVIDERS,
        provide(AuthHttp, {
            useValue: {
                get: (url: string) => {
                    return response;
                }
            }
        }),
        AuthService,
        TestComponentBuilder,
        provide(ToastController, {useClass: null}),
        provide(AlertController, {useClass: null}),
        provide(ErrorService, {useClass: StubErrorService}),
        provide(XHRBackend, {useClass: MockBackend}),
        provide(BackendService, {useClass: StubBackendService}),
        provide(Store, {useClass: StubStore}),
        provide(LoggerService, {useClass: StubLoggerService}),
        provide(NavService, {useClass: StubNavService})
    ]);

    // INJECTS

    beforeEach(inject([TestComponentBuilder, AuthService, ErrorService, BackendService, Store, LoggerService, NavService], (_tcb, as, es, bs, s, ls, ns) => {
        tcb = _tcb;
        authService = as;
        navService = ns;
        errorService = es;
        store = s;
        backendService = bs;
        loggerService = ls;
    }));

    it("should test authservice", () => {
        authService.logout();
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know if its relevant anymore, just to say I had an almost identical issue and I resolved it following the [official docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#isolated-service-tests) on how to test services. Hope it helps!

Comment: Link-only answers aren't useful once the link dies. Please copy the relevant portion of the solution to the answer.

Comment: An answer technically just saying "read the docs" is not useful at all. Especially that linked page results (as of 2017-12-28) in a 91 pages word document _(or at least 77 pages if I print directly from web hiding all side navigations)_ having over 15,000 words.